# Can't solve the following Visual 2008 error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-access-2007

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState& originalState)
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
  at DataSet1TableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter.GetData()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Development Environment is Visual Studio 2008
Operating System is Windows 7 (64 bit)
Database is Access 2007.

Comment: Project + Properties, Build tab, change the Platform target setting from AnyCPU to x86.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components" should give you the correct driver

Comment: i download and installed the Access Engine but still the same error. and changing AnyCPU to x86 also generating the same error